# Show that a subset A is irreducible if and only if its closure is irreducible.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The "if" is easy to prove.

The "only if" part:

Suppose $\bar{A}$ is reducible and $\bar{A}=X_1 \cup X_2$ where $X_i$ are closed subset.

Then $A=(X_1 \cap A)\cup(X_2 \cap A)$. I found proof from other notes that this means $A$ is reducible, which leads to a contradiction.

But I don't understand why this means $A$ is reducible, since we don't know whether $X_i \cap A$ is open or close. By definition $A$ is reducible if it can be written as union of closed subsets. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $i=1,2$, $X_i$ is closed in the whole space, so $X_i\cap A$ is closed in the relative topology on $A$. Thus, $A$ is the union of two proper (relatively) closed subsets of $A$ and is therefore reducible. The subsets $X_i\cap A$ don’t have to be closed in the whole space: all that matters is that they’re closed as subsets of $A$.

Comment: Note one should also verify that the $X_i \cap A$ are non-trivial subsets of $A$. Indeed: suppose $X_i \cap A = A$, then $X_i$ must also contain $\overline{A}$ by definition of the closure, which is a contradiction because $X_i \cap \overline{A}$ is supposed to be a non-trivial closed in $\overline{A}$. Conversely $X_i \cap A = \emptyset$ implies $X_j \cap A = A$ for $j\neq i$.